# How to get Java custom annotations from Implementation class methods

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-aop

For one of my requirment i have created a inteface with multiple methods and  each method annotated with my own java custom annotation.
I have a spring aop aspect for my implementation class and i am not able to get my custom annotation in aop aspect.
after doing debug i understood my custom annotation is part of the interface and not in implementation class.

How can i get my custom annotation in my implementation methods which declared in interface ?

Comment: Post the relevant code.

Comment: You can do it by reflection but could you show a source code how you try to get  it and your custom annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, annotations are not inhereted from interfaces.With aspects you must annotate the implementation class (and/or methods within that class), not the interface (if any) that the class implements. String aop follows Java’s rule that annotations on interfaces are not inherited.
So, if  you want to work with your annotation , create an abstract super class to be able to do this.

Inside aspect you work with proxy object and methods are wrapped in proxy calls. But if you know a real class/interface , you can get annotation by reflection api from source class/interface

Comment: Thanks for the information . For my scenario the interface is implemented by the Spring Integration hence i can't go with the abstract class. I solved this by annotating the interface methods with custom annotation and in my aspect i used reflection to read the annotation values . This solved my problem.